# Why am I getting code 200 deprecated in this Foursquare API call?

Tags: api, foursquare

I'm doing a checkin using the Foursquare API and I'm getting back code 200 deprecated.

Here is a sample URL that is causing this issue:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/add?oauth_token=S1CRKUAV455MDPNEL1FCLLNMVSWXHH2OBKW43DDOPX2LTN1P&venueId=4ed6316a2c5b3d826e649dbf&v=20130718

Replace the oauth_token with any oauth_token and you'll see the issue.

Does anyone know why? I don't see any reason why this is happening...

Comment: To be clear, the HTTP code is 200 but you're seeing a `deprecated` `errorType`? Can you post a relevant sample response?

Answer (score 0):

How are you generating the request. It has to be a POST request! What response object are you getting exactly?